# Rails: find latest Story but based on date in a second model (Article)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logic

So two models: Articles are contained within Stories. A Story can have many Articles and an Article can belong to more than one Story. In between there is a stories_articles table to join them together.

In the sidebar, there is a little box with a list of stories. It is easy to make this **Latest Stories** but this is based on Story.created_at, or **Latest ACTIVE Stories** based on a check-box on the Story form.

But that involves a lot of effort to remember which Stories are still active.

Maybe a new Article is written for a Story that has been dormant for a while, one that was actually created months ago, and so is no longer on the little Story list. I need to let readers know there is a new Article in that Story.

So what I really want to display is **Latest Stories With New Articles** in the sidebar box, and have the Story with the Latest Article shoved to the top of the box.

Something along the lines of… "SELECT Stories ORDER BY Article.created_at"

What is the correct way to find this in rails? What's the query? A join? A merge?

Comment: There is a Query Method called `merge` which you can use to merge together named scopes between 2 different models. So, first join the 2 models then merge in a scope from the Article model that does what you need there.

Comment: Couldn't work this one out with merge and joins either, but thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I went with a version of pavan's answer, which didn't quite work. Reading around, I couldn't work out how to make it work with joins and merge through a third table that contains all the ids. This is what I did:

1. Add a last_active datetime column to the story model, as pavan suggested, and add `:last_active`to params in `stories_controller.rb.
2. To get the latest datetime in there, put the following method in `articles_controller.rb`, and then put `story_latest_active` in the `create` and `update` actions. Each article can belong to several stories. This method now updates the story `last_active` column every time we press `publish` or `update`.

   ```
   def story_last_active
     @article.stories.each do |story|
       story.last_active = Time.now
       story.save
     end
   end
   ```
3. To get it out of the database for the views, first define the scope in `story.rb`, we called it `latest`; this selects and orders the stories by the new `last_active` column

   ```
   scope :latest, -> {order('last_active DESC NULLS LAST, story ASC').limit(5)}
   ```
4. Then, in `application_controller.rb` (we need the list site wide, across several controllers), just put the Story scope in a method:

   ```
   def app_wide
     @last_active_stories = Story.latest
   end
   ```
5. And then in `application.html` for the views (again site wide, but this would work in your views), call the method, cycle through the results and do what you want with them:

   ```
   <% @last_active_stories.each do |story| %>
     <%= link_to story.story, story %>
   <% end %>
   ```

And that works.

Thanks for all your ideas.

Answer (score 0):

U can do something like this.
Add new column to your Story DB maybe last_active:datetime 
In Story Model add a method

```
def some_method
  self.last_active = Time.now
end
```

In controller where you create a new article call this method on @stroy object which u use to create new article( after @article is saved successfully)

In controller where you fetch all stories

```
@stories = Story.all.order("datetime(last_active) DESC")
```

Comment: Thanks @pavan, that nearly worked. It gave me a great start (have a read through the answer). The main obstacle with your suggestion was that by putting the method in the Story model with `self`, it would just update `last_active' every time I opened up a story (i.e. it didn't seem to be related to the act of publishing a new article in that story). But you got me going, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This will list latest 10 active stories

```
Story.unscoped.joins("inner join stories_articles on stories_articles.stroy_id = stories.id")
.joins('inner join articles on articles.id = stories_articles.article_id') #joins story to article through stories_articles

.group('stories.id')  # forms list of distinct stories
.order('articles.created_at') #sort 
.first(10)
```